# Can I share extremely well technical blog/code library links with community?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, share-this

Can I share extremely well technical blog/code library links with Stack Overflow community? Or should I have to make a dummy problem situation that relates to my intentionally link posting. And then give a library link and accepted my own answer, so that other can also take benefit of it?

What I understand is it might confuse some users, whether the available code library is reliable or not.

Or should I not share any technical blog/code library/plugin links with the users?

Comment: "Or should I have to make a dummy problem situation that anyhow related to my intent link posting." Not just *anyhow*, please. It has to be a practical problem you're facing.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn. Sorry, that was grammatical mistake. I edited to show my sense of asking the question. :)

Comment: If you just want to share a link, then question comments are usually sufficient. You can certainly also find existing topics instead of posting new ones. If your intent is commercial promotion of a product or your blog, refrain.

Comment: That kind of thing is permitted, but should be sprinkled on like spices on food. Too much is going to leave a very bad taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to share that kind of information, you need to ask a question that the information you have can answer. It's perfectly fine to link external resources provided that:

- Your post can stand on its own even if the link breaks. Summarize the information you're referencing and cite the important bits. Nothing is worse than finding something highly up voted that helped everyone *but* you due to link rot.
- Openly indicate that you are the author or affiliated with the external resource if that is the case, and avoid being spammy. If the links all lead back to your site, you're probably going to get an adverse reaction.
- Make sure you're not duplicating existing questions, creating a question that is too broad or open ended, and otherwise fits within our question guidelines.
- Not required, but it can be helpful to leave a comment under your question indicating that you intend to answer it yourself. Some of our users get rather upset when they spend time creating an answer and the original question author just writes their own. They shouldn't, it's supposed to be all about sharing information - but it does happen from time to time.

Just use a bit of common sense and keep *clearly* in mind that the community is ***extremely*** sensitive to SPAM. If you can do that, you should not have a problem. If you actually *create* questions just so you can answer them with links to things you are affiliated with, you'll likely have some cozy one to one time with a moderator.

Comment: "Extremely sensitive to SPAM"... why Tim, whatever do you mean?? *twitches*